# Is there an existing admin / config model for building a list of key-value pairs?

Tags: admin, configuration, adminhtml, system.xml

I'm working on a new extension which has the need for some user defined key-value pairs.  In the system config area of the admin panel the user will need to enter several values such as:

```
"some/relative/path" -> "some external uri"
"some/relative/path" -> "some external uri"
"some/relative/path" -> "some external uri"
```

In the admin panel I'd like to present the user with two side-by-side text boxes, with validation that requires entries in both boxes to submit.

Is there an existing model that has that functionality?

Comment: Are you building your own form or using the system.xml? Do you want client or server sided validation? This does sound like a view related task, not something which is to be solved by the choice of a model.

Comment: I'm looking for a system.xml implementation in the admin panel--validation can be server side.  Basically I'm looking for an example of a single system config entry which requires multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <something translate="label" module="mname">
            <label>something</label>
            <sort_order>550</sort_order>
        </something>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <some translate="label" module="mname">
            <label>first section</label>
            <tab>your tab</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <relative translate="label, comment">
                    <label>first group</label>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <fields>
                        <path1>
                            <label>first field</label>
                            <comment>description</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </path1>
                        <path2>
                            <label>second field</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </path2>
                        <path3>
                            <label>third and last field</label>             
                            <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </path3>
                    </fields>
                </relative>
            </groups>
        </some>
    </sections>
</config>
```

this will create keys some/relative/path1, some/relative/path2 and some/relative/path3 with user values in core_config_data.

It can be used elsewhere in the code with :

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('some/relative/path1');
```